# How to upload encoded base64 image to the server using spring

Tags: spring

I'm writing a webservice using spring.
This service takes the base64 encoded image as a String parameter.
I want to decode this String into image and upload into server.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadImage",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadImage(@RequestParam("encodedImage") String encodedImage)
{
    byte[] imageByte= Base64.decodeBase64(encodedImage);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The below code is used to decode the string which is encoded by using base 64 and used to upload image into the server.

This working fine for me..

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadImage2",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String uploadImage2(@RequestParam("imageValue") String imageValue,HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            //This will decode the String which is encoded by using Base64 class
            byte[] imageByte=Base64.decodeBase64(imageValue);

            String directory=servletContext.getRealPath("/")+"images/sample.jpg";

            new FileOutputStream(directory).write(imageByte);
            return "success ";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return "error = "+e;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I had to split the imageValue at the first comma and take the remainder since I sent the entire image including the "header". Also, it is Base64.getDecoder().decode() if you use java.util.Base64. Hope these two tidbits help someone.

Answer (score 4):

Use Java's [`Base64.Decoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html) to decode the string to a byte array.

If that's not available in your version of Java, you can use the same functionality from the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/index.html) project.

Comment: now i can decode it by using the below code.                      byte[] imageByte= Base64.decodeBase64(response.getImageString());   But i need to change it to file(or image) format

Comment: no. i decoded the string into byte[] only but i want to change it file.

Comment: Well, you just have to write the byte array to a file then, for example by using a [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Comment: FileWriter is for text files. FileOutputStream would be more appropriate.

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't check properly. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Actually i have a code to upload multipart image into the server. But my client sends the image into encoded base64 format. so i want to change that encoded string into the multipart file..

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using Spring you could consider using an HttpMessageConverter to convert your image to a BufferedImage before it reaches your controllers. I couldn't find an already made one in the spring converters (maybe I missed it?). In any case this is something I just wrote now. You may be able to improve it.**

```
 package com.stuff;

    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.StringWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;

    /**
     * @author John Deverall
     */
    public class Base64EncodedImageHttpMessageConverter extends
            AbstractHttpMessageConverter<BufferedImage> {

        private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

        public Base64EncodedImageHttpMessageConverter() {

            List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
            String[] supportedMediaTypes = ImageIO.getReaderMIMETypes();
            for (String supportedMediaType : supportedMediaTypes) {
                String[] typeAndSubtype = supportedMediaType.split("/");
                mediaTypes.add(new MediaType(typeAndSubtype[0], typeAndSubtype[1]));
            }

            setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);   
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
            return clazz.equals(BufferedImage.class);
        }

        /** This uses a data uri. If that's not you, 
         * you'll need to modify this method to decode the base64 data
         * straight. */
        @Override
        protected BufferedImage readInternal(Class<? extends BufferedImage> clazz,
                HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException,
                HttpMessageNotReadableException {

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputMessage.getBody(), writer, "UTF-8");
            String imageInBase64 = writer.toString();
            int startOfBase64Data = imageInBase64.indexOf(",") + 1;
            imageInBase64 = imageInBase64.substring(startOfBase64Data,
                    imageInBase64.length());

            if (Base64.isBase64(imageInBase64) == false) {
                logger.error("************************************************");
                logger.error("*** IMAGE IN REQUEST IS NOT IN BASE64 FORMAT ***");
                logger.error("************************************************");
            }

            byte[] decodeBase64 = Base64.decodeBase64(imageInBase64);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    decodeBase64));
            return image;

        }     

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(BufferedImage t,
                HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException,
                HttpMessageNotWritableException {
            ImageIO.write(t, "jpeg", outputMessage.getBody());
            outputMessage.getBody().flush();
        }

    }
```

**Then in your controller, write something like this (or preferably pass the BufferedImage to some kind of service). Notice that the conversion logic from base64 to the BufferedImage is reusable and hidden in the HttpMessageConverter.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void saveImage(@PathVariable String memberId, @RequestBody BufferedImage image)  {     
        someService.setBufferedImage(image);
    }



@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody BufferedImage getImage() { 
        BufferedImage image = someService.getBufferedImage();
        return image;
    }
```

**If you're using spring's java configuration, configuration of HttpMessageConverters looks something like this**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
        public void configureMessageConverters(
                List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            converters.add(getJsonConverter());
            converters.add(getImageConverter());
            super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
        }

        @Bean
        GsonHttpMessageConverter getJsonConverter() { 
            GsonHttpMessageConverter converter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
            return converter;
        }

        @Bean
        Base64EncodedImageHttpMessageConverter getImageConverter() { 
            Base64EncodedImageHttpMessageConverter converter = new Base64EncodedImageHttpMessageConverter();
            return converter;
        }

}
```

If you like, you could avoid using apache commons if you don't need it and just go with the new java8 java.util.base64 class. The GsonHttpMessageConverter (for converting Json to my domain objects) is not used for images either so you can pull that out of the config if images is all you're doing.

Comment: Note you could also avoid using apache commons here if you don't need it and just go with the new java8 java.util.base64 class. The GsonHttpMessageConverter (for converting Json to my domain objects) is not used for images either so you can pull that out of the config if images is all you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

**Following is working for me:**

```
package com.SmartBitPixel.XYZ.pqr.Controllers;

import java.util.Base64;    
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;    
import java.io.File;    
import java.io.FileOutputStream;    
import java.util.Base64;    
import java.util.List;    
import java.util.Locale;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;    
import org.slf4j.Logger;    
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;    
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;    
import org.springframework.ui.Model;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;    
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;    

@Controller    
public class MainDocController     
{    
  @RequestMapping(value="/ProfileRegSubmit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFileUpload( 
            @RequestParam("fName") String fName, @RequestParam("lName") String lName,
            @RequestParam("imgName") String imgName, @RequestParam("webcamScanImage") String scanImageFile )
    {       

        if (!scanImageFile.isEmpty()) 
        {
            try 
            {               
                byte[] scanBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(scanImageFile);


                                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Creating the directory to store file/data/image ////////////

                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");

                File fileSaveDir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIR);

                // Creates the save directory if it does not exists
                if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) 
                {
                    fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
                }

                File scanFile = new File( fileSaveDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "scanImageFile.png");
                BufferedOutputStream scanStream = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( scanFile ) );       
                scanStream.write(scanBytes);
                scanStream.close();

                returnStr = "RegisterSuccessful";

            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                returnStr = "You failed to upload scanImageFile => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            returnStr = "You failed to upload scanImageFile because the file is empty.";
        }
    }
}
```